# Android - Opencv - error: (-215) u != 0 in function void cv::Mat::create

Tags: java, opencv, android

My app keeps crashing with this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-22883
    Process: com.aar.Cline, PID: 7270
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:424: error: (-215) u != 0 in function void cv::Mat::create(int, const int*, int)
    ]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:1724)
    at com.aar.Cline.TrackBallActivity.detectBall(TrackBallActivity.java:592)
    at com.aar.Cline.TrackBallActivity.onCameraFrame(TrackBallActivity.java:190)
    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:391)
    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:350)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The app is running fine for about 3 min when suddenly in the middle this error shows up here is the line on which it keeps crashing

```
Mat grayImage1 = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(frame1, grayImage1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error happens [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L426). It means that you can't allocate enough memory. You're basically out of memory. Instead of creating new matrices every time, you'd better allocate them once (as class members) and reuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `new` keyword, you are allocating memory for the `Mat()` object on the [free store](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm) (often the same thing as the [heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)). This requires you to explicitly `delete` this object later. As you are not doing that, you created a memory leak which causes your app to crash. Therefore, for every `new`, you must have a corresponding `delete`.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
Mat *grayImage1 = new Mat();
delete grayImage1;
```

To avoid dynamic allocation, I would simply do something like this:

```
Mat grayImage1 = frame1.gray();
```